# View model property is null on POST in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have an issue with my view where on HTTP POST the view model returns `null` for all of my properties.

Below is my view model.

```
public class CustomerVM
{
    public List<CustomerCDTO> customerCDTO { get; set; }
}
```

In the above view model I have created a `List<CustomerCDTO>` property. The `CustomerCDTO` class definition is as follows.

```
public class CustomerCDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool? IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my view:

```
<%foreach (var item in Model.customerCDTO) {%>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center; width: 10%;" class="table-content-middle">
        <%if (item.Active == true)
        {%>
            <%=Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>item.Active)%>
        <%}
        else
        { %>
            <%=Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>item.Active)%>
        <%}%>
    </td>
    <td class="table-content-middle" align="center" style="width: 80%;">
        <%: item.Name%>
    </td>
</tr>
<%} %>
```

When I perform an HTTP GET everything works as expected but on POST I am getting `null` for `CustomerVM.customerCDTO`.

Please suggest what should I do to make it work.

thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are not getting to each `CustomerCDTO` with expressions containing the information that it's part of a `List`.

Use a `for` loop instead:

```
<%for (var i = 0; i < Model.customerCDTO.Count; ++i)
```

And refer to the elements with expressions like

```
<%=Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.customerCDTO[i].Active)%>
```

Basically you need to have the expression `m => ...` resolve to the property you are interested in starting from `m`, not from some other variable.

Comment: hi all, it is working fine for my <%=Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>item.Active)%> but it is not giving me null for <%: item.Name%>...please suggest

Comment: @aamankhaan: What is `item`? There is no such variable in the answer.

Comment: i have modified my code as per answer only below goes the full view.
<%for (var i = 0; i < Model.customerCDTO.Count();i++)
  {%>
  <tr>
     <td style="text-align: center; width: 10%;" class="table-content-middle">
     <%if (Model.customerCDTO[i].Active == true)
      {%>
      <%=Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.customerCDTO[i].Active)%>
      <%}
      else
      { %>
      <%=Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.customerCDTO[i].Active)%>
    <%} %>
     </td>
     <td class="table-content-middle" align="center" style="width: 80%;">
    <%=Html.DisplayTextFor(m=>m.customerCDTO[i].Name)%>
    </td>     </tr>
<%} %>

Comment: sorry for the above comment too jazzy please find the below link with whole discription http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514322/viewmodel-return-null-on-httppost