# viewmodel return null on HttpPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

i have created a view like below.

```
<%for (var i = 0; i < Model.customerCDTO.Count();i++)
  {%>
  <tr>
     <td style="text-align: center; width: 10%;" class="table-content-middle">
     <%if (Model.customerCDTO[i].Active == true)
      {%>
      <%=Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.customerCDTO[i].Active)%>
      <%}
      else
      { %>
      <%=Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.customerCDTO[i].Active)%>
    <%} %>
     </td>
     <td class="table-content-middle" align="center" style="width: 80%;">
     <%=Html.DisplayTextFor(m=>m.customerCDTO[i].Name)%>
     </td>
     </tr>
 <%} %>
```

the problem with the above view is that it is giving value for null for customerCDTO[i].Name

below is my view model

```
public class CustomerVM
{
public List<CustomerCDTO> customerCDTO { get; set; }
}
```

In the above view model I have created a List property. The CustomerCDTO class definition is as follows.

```
public class CustomerCDTO
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public bool Active { get; set; }
public bool? IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

please help.

thanks

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: my controller simply getting the records from the database and displaying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's giving you a `null` value because your form does not contain any `<input>` elements corresponding to the `Name` property (which you can immediately spot if you View Source). The reason for this is that `DisplayTextFor` is not supposed to create such elements in the first place.

An **almost always bad idea** would be to also call `Html.HiddenFor`, which *does* create input elements:

```
<td class="table-content-middle" align="center" style="width: 80%;">
    <%=Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.customerCDTO[i].Name)%>
    <%=Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.customerCDTO[i].Name)%>
</td>
```

This would solve your problem, but then the user could simply edit the values with a tool like Firebug and change the value of `Name`, which you obviously do not want since otherwise you 'd have presented an `<input>` element for that. (Note: I also changed `DisplayTextFor` to `DisplayFor`, which in general is the more correct way to do things).

But what to do then? Well, there's no magic solution here. If the form doesn't contain `Name` then it will be `null`, but if it *does* contain `Name` (even hidden) then the user can change it at will. If that's a problem, the only option is to modify your backend code to populate `Name` from your data store.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make sure that your list is populated with your intended data after running your query against database. In fact, it seems like your data is not populated properly.

Comment: hi every thing is working properly only issue is on postback occurs.